# git set-upstream-to=origin/master (local copy of remote)

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I have read many answers about "origin/master" where they say it's a local copy of the remote origin of branch master. I'm confused when I read about set-upstream-to where it should refer to remote branch master , so can anyone explain why set-upstream-to reference to local copy instead of remote ? like `git push origin master` not `git push origin/master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion about references in the basic Git commands.  And you should have confusion, because it's confusing.

The local branch `master`, which exists only in your local Git repo, is in what you do most of your actual development work.  Similarly, there is also a branch called `master` which exists on the remote.  Now, for the confusion, there is a *third* branch called `origin/master`.  This is a *local* branch, which exists on your local repo.  It exists mainly to serve as a proxy for the true remote `master` branch.  Whenever you sync with the remote `master` branch, locally you are actually using `origin/master`.

Doing `git pull origin master` is actually identical to this (assuming you are using the merge strategy by default):

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

The first step, `git fetch origin`, updates the local tracking branch `origin/master` with the latest changes, such that it mirrors the true `master` branch on the remote.  Then, it does a merge into your local `master` branch using `origin/master`.  Here is a brief summary:

```
master        | the master branch (either local or remote)
origin master | the master branch on the remote (as in the git pull command)
origin/master | local tracking branch for master which mirrors the remote version
```

So, keeping in mind that `origin/master` is the actual branch which tracks the true remote `master` branch, we can tell Git to use `origin/master` as the tracking branch via:

```
# from local master branch
git --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

Note that if you create or checkout `master` locally, Git typically would create `origin/master` as the default tracking branch behind the scenes.  So, in practice, you probably won't have to use `--set-upstream-to` very often.

Comment: exactly that's what I'm understanding. My confusion is about set-upstream-to , why it's used with "origin/master" not " origin master"  , because we need the upstream for the master branch on remote

Comment: @MohammadKarmi `origin master`, by itself, doesn't really mean anything.  As used inside of `git pull origin master`, `origin master` refers to the true `master` branch living on the remote.  But, setting the upstream is all about telling Git which _local_ tracking branch to be used for `git pull`.  So, this is why you point to `origin/master`.